# Fastboot commands are not working

Tags: fastboot

I have tried to relock my Zenfone Max pro m2,but after installing stock recovery when I tried to run `relock.cmd`, it is not working showing that

```
write to device failed(invalid argument)
```

Even when I have tried to find the device info using fastboot command, but I'm getting the same error as

```
write to device failed( too many links)
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: I don't get it: where are you issuing fastboot commands? Are you on bootloader mode or in recovery mode?

Comment: Bootloader mode

Comment: Did you enable OEM unlocking in development options?

Comment: Yes , I have enabled usb debugging

Comment: No, I mean OEM unlocking

Comment: No , that is not turned on

Comment: Go back there and enable OEM unlocking. Reboot from ADB to recovery then run relock.cmd file

Comment: But that is not listed in developer options

Comment: Hum don't own this phone, so I cannot check. Try instructions from here: https://forum.xda-developers.com/asus-zenfone-max-pro-m1/how-to/discussion-unlocking-bootloader-t3786698/post76439671#post76439671

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you are running relock.cmd as a file or a command, but the usual way to lock the bootloader in Fastboot is

```
fastboot oem lock
```

Try

```
fastboot devices
```

And wait until you see your device is found, then do the lock

```
fastboot oem lock
```

---

Try also,

```
fastboot flashing lock     
fastboot flashing lock_critical
```

Comment: Those commands are not working

Comment: Try fastboot flashing lock  - or - fastboot flashing lock_critical

Comment: Yeah it worked ...!!!! , i tried changing the usb port. and thanks for your suggestions